# PEFT using Lora-Adapter

Tags: python, large-language-model

Fine-tuning LORA-Adapter for Text generation with gpt2

```
import wandb
from datasets import load_dataset
import numpy as np
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
from pprint import pprint
from datasets import concatenate_datasets
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM
from peft import LoraConfig, get_peft_model 
from transformers import Trainer, TrainingArguments, DataCollatorForLanguageModeling
```

```
wandb.login()



wandb.init(project="my_model",
           config={
               "learning_rate": 1e-3,
               "architecture": "GPT2",
               "dataset": "SAMSUM",
               "epochs": 1,
           })
```

```
raw_datasets = load_dataset("samsum")
```

```
checkpoint = 'gpt2'
tokenizer=AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(checkpoint)

if tokenizer.pad_token is None:
    tokenizer.add_special_tokens({'pad_token': tokenizer.eos_token})
tokenised_sentences=tokenizer(raw_datasets['train'][0:3]['summary'])
pprint(tokenised_sentences)
```

```
tokenized_inputs = concatenate_datasets([raw_datasets["train"], raw_datasets["test"]]).map(lambda x: tokenizer(x["dialogue"], truncation=True), batched=True, remove_columns=["dialogue", "summary"])

input_lenghts = [len(x) for x in tokenized_inputs["input_ids"]]

max_source_length = int(np.percentile(input_lenghts, 85))

tokenized_targets = concatenate_datasets([raw_datasets["train"], raw_datasets["test"]]).map(lambda x: tokenizer(x["summary"], truncation=True), batched=True, remove_columns=["dialogue", "summary"])

target_lenghts = [len(x) for x in tokenized_targets["input_ids"]]

max_target_length = int(np.percentile(target_lenghts, 90))

print(f"Max target length: {max_target_length}")
```

```
def preprocess_function(sample,padding="max_length"):
    inputs = ["summarize: " + item for item in sample["dialogue"]]
    model_inputs = tokenizer(inputs, max_length=max_source_length, padding=padding, truncation=True)
    labels = tokenizer(text_target=sample["summary"], max_length=max_target_length, padding=padding, truncation=True)
    if padding == "max_length":
        labels["input_ids"] = [
            [(l if l != tokenizer.pad_token_id else -100) for l in label] for label in labels["input_ids"]
        ]

    model_inputs["labels"] = labels["input_ids"]
    return model_inputs
```

```
tokenized_dataset = raw_datasets.map(preprocess_function, batched=True, remove_columns=["dialogue", "summary", "id"])

tokenized_dataset["train"].save_to_disk("data/train")

tokenized_dataset["test"].save_to_disk("data/eval")
```

```
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    checkpoint, 
    device_map='auto',
)
```

```
config = LoraConfig(
    r=16,
    lora_alpha=32,
    target_modules=["c_attn", "c_proj"],
    lora_dropout=0.05,
    bias="none",
    task_type="CAUSAL_LM"
)
model = get_peft_model(model, config)
```

```
output_dir = "lora-gpt2"
training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir=output_dir,
    learning_rate=1e-3,
    num_train_epochs=1,
    logging_dir=f"{output_dir}/logs",
    logging_strategy="steps",
    logging_steps=500,
    save_strategy="no",
    report_to="wandb",
    run_name="my_model",
    per_device_train_batch_size=2,
)
```

```
data_collator = DataCollatorForLanguageModeling(
    tokenizer=tokenizer, 
    mlm=False,
)
```

```
trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    data_collator=data_collator,
    train_dataset=tokenized_dataset['train'],
    eval_dataset=tokenized_dataset['validation']
)
model.config.use_cache = False 
trainer.train()
```

```
eval_results = trainer.evaluate()
```

```
print(f"Perplexity: {torch.exp(torch.tensor(eval_results['eval_loss']))}")
```

So basically I have tried to Fine-Tune using lora-adapter and atlast calculated the perplexity matrix for my model

Can anyone tell me why I am getting the perplexity as inf

print(f"Perplexity: {torch.exp(torch.tensor(eval_results['eval_loss']))}")

Perplexity: inf